# Use only querystrings throughout the project, avoid session in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, session, webforms

We are developing an asp.net webforms app. We want to avoid using session state if possible, passing values in the querystring.

**Question:** After a user logs in, how do we keep the user from linking and reusing a url.

Is there a token of some type we can set on login that expires after a certain time?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ASP.NET Forms authentication, you can set the timeout for the cookie in the web.config, as explained here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/1d3t3c61(v=vs.100)